# Is there a way to integrate the cloud icon to download content

Tags: ios

I made a Calculus video app and I would like to add the capability to download the videos for offline use. I could create a button and have my own icon of course but I am trying to see if there is a way to integrate the little cloud icon that apple uses in its WWDC app (and App store app) for downloads(see screenshot below) [image: cloud icon]

Comment: Find or create your own icon. That's not a standard icon available through any API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no native cloud icon burned into iOS.

Your best shot is to just make your own icon and set the image as the accessory view on the cell.